# Proxy settings are not applied for eclipse , getting error when click on eclipse market place

Tags: java, eclipse, proxy

Given the correct proxy settings in eclipse
but getting error when click on eclipse market place [enter proxysetting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI3xJ.png)

[eclipse error when click on market place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZclc.png)

In case of android studio its working fine by accepting certificate [[androidstudiocertificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIFtf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to configure your proxy also for the https schema (not just http)?

Are you certain you do not need to supply credentials?

Comment: I configured https schema as well
i am certain , credentails are not needed

Comment: proxy settings works fine with android studio after accepting certificate as attached in question

Comment: I had only thought about https because in your screenshot the slot is empty. :)